# ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in UserController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have started with learning rails and for that purpose i begin with developing a shipping app with nested attributes. Basically i have model `User` , `Box` and `BoxKind` table with HABTM between `Box` and `Kind`.

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :boxes
accepts_nested_attributes_for :boxes
end
```

**Box Model**

```
class Box < ActiveRecord::Base    
belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => "user_id"    
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

has_and_belongs_to_many :kinds, join_table: :boxes_kinds    
accepts_nested_attributes_for :kinds
end
```

**Kind Model**

```
class Kind < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :boxes, join_table: :boxes_kinds
end
```

When i try to add new record to the database I am getting an `unknown attribute: box_id` error. This is a bit confusing to me hence i have added custom primary key to the `Box` model called `ref_no`.

Where am I wrong ?

**UPDATE** As @NitinVerma requested in addition is the console log :

```
Started POST "/user" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-18 19:27:11 +1000
Processing by UserController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Xt5OvI9hfU98rHQ0fGb5NDui1lRg0Bned8+03Hurr1Y=", "user"=>{"name"=>"Mark", "email"=>"mark@abc.com", "address"=>"Some address ", "postcode"=>"1928", "tel_no"=>"0394884994", "state"=>"VIC", "boxes_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"ref_no"=>"1005", "quantity"=>"2", "kinds_attributes"=>{"1408354027248"=>{"big"=>"2", "small"=>"", "odd"=>"", "trunck"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "0"=>{"big"=>"", "small"=>"",  "_destroy"=>"1"}}, "collected_at(1i)"=>"2012", "collected_at(2i)"=>"8", "collected_at(3i)"=>"18", "collected_at(4i)"=>"08", "collected_at(5i)"=>"59", "destination_country"=>"UK", "destination_country_address"=>"Regency  Street 18", "shipped"=>"1", "shipped_at(1i)"=>"2014", "shipped_at(2i)"=>"8", "shipped_at(3i)"=>"18", "shipped_at(4i)"=>"08", "shipped_at(5i)"=>"59", "reached"=>"0", "reached_at(1i)"=>"2014", "reached_at(2i)"=>"8", "reached_at(3i)"=>"18", "reached_at(4i)"=>"08", "reached_at(5i)"=>"59"}}}, "commit"=>"Submit"}

Unpermitted parameters: _destroy
Unpermitted parameters: _destroy

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 32ms

ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: box_id):
  app/controllers/user_controller.rb:21:in `create'
```

Comment: can you paste your console log here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HABTM**

I think the problem is your `habtm` table:

```
create_table "boxes_kinds", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer "ref_no",  null: false
    t.integer "kind_id", null: false
end
```

Rails `has_and_belongs_to_many` tables are meant to contain the `foreign_key` for each of the associated tables:

[image]

The problem you have is that since *your* table has `box_id` as `ref_no`, Rails is unable to determine the column to save the value to; hence invoking the exception you're seeing.

I would recommend using the `association_foreign_key` or the `foreign_key` arguments for your `has_and_belongs_to_many` association:

```
#app/models/box.rb
Class Box < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :kinds, foreign_key: "ref_no"
end

#app/models/kind.rb
Class Kind < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :boxes, association_foreign_key: "ref_no"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to change boxes_kinds table. remove ref_no and add box_id. Because join table saves id column of associated tables like `#{model_name}_id` . Also you need to remove id column from user permit params or say parent permit params. id column only need for child models. Also optionally if you want to destroy any associated child object while editing parent you can add _destory to permit params.

```
def user_box_params

    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :address, :postcode, :tel_no, :state, 

     boxes_attributes: [:id, :ref_no, :quantity, :collected_at, :destination_country, :destination_country_address, :shipped, :shipped_at, :reached, :reached_at, _destroy,

     kinds_attributes: [:id, :big, :small, :odd, :trunck, _destroy]]) 
end
```